# How to Upgrade TYPO3 7.6.x to 8.x.0

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x

What are the required steps to upgrade TYPO3 7.6.x to 8.X?. Currently My project running on TYPO3 7.6.15 and linux systems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only requirement that changes when you update from TYPO3 7 LTS to TYPO3 8 LTS ist the PHP version.

TYPO3 8 LTS requires at least PHP 7.0.

So first of all you need a local environment and a server with PHP 7.0 or 7.1. Then make a copy of your project (keep the original as a backup and a reference) and check all extensions. You want to know a) if you still need them and b) if they are already available for TYPO3 8LTS. If they are, you are fine, if they are not, you have to find an alternative, disable the extension (temporarily) or just wait with the update.

You then update the core and the extensions to the latest releases and go to the install tool. First you want to compare the DB structure to add new fields and tables (don't remove anything yet). After that go to the Upgrade Wizards and perform all of them that are not marked as "optional". Perform the optionals as you need them.

Now your backend should work if no extension breaks it. Your next steps are testing the functionalities that are provided by your extensions and make sure they still work. You might also want to have a look at the breaking changes of the TYPO3 core since 7 LTS to see if your system might be affected. Those can also be found in the install tool (Upgrade Analysis) and they usually have a migration documented.

You can find additional advice regarding updates of TYPO3 systems here: https://usetypo3.com/upgrading-projects.html